# Does chocolate hurt hamsters?

Tags: feeding, hamsters

I know that chocolate is bad for dogs, but is it bad for hamsters too? I would like an answer from a credible source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Chocolate can be very harmful to hamsters, even lethal. Chocolate contains   theobromine (aka 3,7- Dimethylxanthine) which remains in the systems for prolonged periods. This has a toxic effect, as a hamster is such a small animal, a small ingestion of chocolate will release a larger proportion of theobromine per kg of body weight than a human eating the same amount. Prolonged ingestion of theobromine can cause testicular damage.

> Theobromine is the principal alkaloid of the cacao bean. It is extracted from
>   the bean husks and used in the synthesis of caffeine. It has been used in various
>   pharmaceutical products. Theobromine is consumed in coco a and chocolate
>   beverages and in various forms of chocolate-based foods. Theobromine is also
>   present in small amounts in green coffee beans, tea and mate. (1)

- The other dangerous ingredient of chocolate is caffeine. Which affects the central nervous system, increasing heart rate and arousal; the reason human beings enjoy ingesting caffeine, in such a small animal as a hamster can lead to stress or even death.
- It should also be noted chocolate can be toxic for unborn hamsters of pregnant hamsters and babies of a nursing hamster, as these, potential, toxins pass through the placenta and breast milk.

The following diagram shows the varying levels of caffeine and theobromine within different chocolate sources.
[image] image courtesy of  St. Francis Animal and Bird Hospital and

---

Referenes:

- Theobromine, IARC MONOGRAHS VOLUME 51 [PDF](http://monographs.iarc.fr/ENG/Monographs/vol51/mono51-12.pdf)  (1)
- [Chocolate Toxicity](http://www.stfrancisanimalandbird.com/ResourcesLibrary/?page_id=386)  St. Francis Animal and Bird Hospital
- [Some food toxic for pets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0AXR.png), Kovalkovičová, et al Interdisciplinary Toxicology 
  Slovak Toxicology Society SETOX & Institute of Experimental Pharmacology and Toxicology, Slovak Academy of Sciences

Comment: Pretty much humans are the only species that really ought to be fed coffee or chocolate. ;p

Comment: I want to add: 1oz are approximately 25g